# Cast void* to int and back

Tags: c, pointers, integer, type-conversion

I'm studying for a test and one of the questions was to implement a system like valgrind for Windows.
My fellow students and I were interested in doing the following:

```
void* ptr = malloc(size);
int ptr_location = (int)ptr;
free( (void*) ptr_location);
```

The reason is to easily manage memory by locations and sizes in a map, instead of holding the pointer itself.

Are these conversions legal, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You must specify exact question.

Comment: Added the question

Comment: @Holt the question you marked is from 2011, has anything changed since?

Comment: @ArikRinberg Nope, nothing in general. If you want an _updated reference_, you can check my answer below which has relevant quote from the latest (`C11`) standard but it's almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking but generally the above example is wrong and non-portable as `int` size and `void *` may differ on various platforms.

If you really want to cast `void *` to some int type, it's better to use `intptr_t` (or `uintptr_t`) which are guaranteed to have (at least) the same size as `void *`.

Comment: intptr_t is a pointer or a number? As if how would I use the type intptr_t

Comment: @ArikRinberg it is a number. One usage would be to replace `int` in your example by `intptr_t`. It is just a special integer type to hold pointers.

Answer (score 3):

It is implementation defined behavior.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3/p6,

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

Rather, you can use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, which are described in §7.20.1.4, as (available in `<stdint.h>`)

> [...] type designates a(n) (un)signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer.